# How to select from mysqli if value from other table equals specific value?

Tags: php, mysqli

I know I should post a code of what I've tried so far. I really don't know where to start. So at this moment I have 2 working mysqli statements, but I don't know how to combine them.

So, I have two tables.

```
$sql_ONE = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM todo WHERE status='open' ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT " . $offset . "," . $items_per_page); 
$sql_TWO = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM permission WHERE memberID=$memberID AND allowed='yes'");
```

I use `$offset` and `$items_per_page` for pagination.

But here it comes: there's a second table that contains a list of members, their memberID and a value (yes/no) wether they may see the row from the first statement or not. So in the first mysqli-statement, all rows are selected where status=open. Before this row's printed on the screen, PHP needs to check if the member who is on the page is allowed to see it. So it should only be shown if allowed=yes.

I don't want them to be in one table, because then I need a row for every single member.

How can I combine those two tables and show them on my screen, still with pagination showing the right amount of rows?

Comment: Which attributes do you want to join?

Comment: I want the ID of sql_ONE. the memberID is already set on user login. So in sql_TWO, I want to see if the value of "allowed" is set to yes or no, where ID = ID (from sql_ONE) and memberID = $memberID.

Comment: Then, when the value=yes, all content from sql_ONE may be visible on screen

Comment: when value=no, it should go to the next row from sql_ONE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know exactly about your database but by so far understanding I have derived this

```
SELECT todo.ID
FROM todo
LEFT JOIN permission
ON todo.ID=permission.ID
where permission.allowed='Yes' AND permission.memberID=$memberID
```

It will join two tables 'todo' and 'perrmission' and will return ID of 'todo' on the basis of condition from permission table.